# Jquery slide show like this

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, show, slide

Is there any jquery slideshow plugin where you have 3 images.The middle one is bigger than other two, and other two have opacity on it.And they have slider controls for right/left?

Comment: Google for "Carousel"

Comment: you should show the code you are trying to use and what you have tried to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the **3D Carousel Gallery** at [this page](https://dcrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-carousel-slider-plugins/) has something alike what you are looking for.